# FreeType Render Glyph AccessViolationException Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, .net, freetype, freetype2

I'm trying to get FreeType v2.6.3 to work in C#. I got everything to work except the rendering part.

[Font.cs](https://github.com/MatthiWare/Flamy2D/blob/freetype-design/Flamy2D/Fonts/Font.cs) (FreeType.Render_Glyph)

```
FreeType.Load_Glyph(facePtr, index, FreeType.FT_LOAD_DEFAULT | FreeType.FT_LOAD_TARGET_NORMAL);
FaceRec faceRec = (FaceRec)Marshal.PtrToStructure(facePtr, typeof(FaceRec));
FreeType.Render_Glyph(faceRec.glyph, FreeType.FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);
GlyphSlotRec glyphRec = (GlyphSlotRec)Marshal.PtrToStructure(faceRec.glyph, typeof(GlyphSlotRec));
```

This calls the DllImport
[FreeType.cs](https://github.com/MatthiWare/Flamy2D/blob/freetype-design/Flamy2D.Freetype/FreeType.cs)

```
public static int Render_Glyph(IntPtr slot, int render_mode)
{
    return FT_Render_Glyph(slot, render_mode);
}

[DllImport("freetype263.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int FT_Render_Glyph(IntPtr slot, int render_mode);
```

The C code freetype.h

```
    /*************************************************************************/
  /*                                                                       */
  /* <Function>                                                            */
  /*    FT_Render_Glyph                                                    */
  /*                                                                       */
  /* <Description>                                                         */
  /*    Convert a given glyph image to a bitmap.  It does so by inspecting */
  /*    the glyph image format, finding the relevant renderer, and         */
  /*    invoking it.                                                       */
  /*                                                                       */
  /* <InOut>                                                               */
  /*    slot        :: A handle to the glyph slot containing the image to  */
  /*                   convert.                                            */
  /*                                                                       */
  /* <Input>                                                               */
  /*    render_mode :: This is the render mode used to render the glyph    */
  /*                   image into a bitmap.  See @FT_Render_Mode for a     */
  /*                   list of possible values.                            */
  /*                                                                       */
  /* <Return>                                                              */
  /*    FreeType error code.  0~means success.                             */
  /*                                                                       */
  /* <Note>                                                                */
  /*    To get meaningful results, font scaling values must be set with    */
  /*    functions like @FT_Set_Char_Size before calling FT_Render_Glyph.   */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    When FreeType outputs a bitmap of a glyph, it really outputs an    */
  /*    alpha coverage map.  If a pixel is completely covered by a         */
  /*    filled-in outline, the bitmap contains 0xFF at that pixel, meaning */
  /*    that 0xFF/0xFF fraction of that pixel is covered, meaning the      */
  /*    pixel is 100% black (or 0% bright).  If a pixel is only 50%        */
  /*    covered (value 0x80), the pixel is made 50% black (50% bright or a */
  /*    middle shade of grey).  0% covered means 0% black (100% bright or  */
  /*    white).                                                            */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    On high-DPI screens like on smartphones and tablets, the pixels    */
  /*    are so small that their chance of being completely covered and     */
  /*    therefore completely black are fairly good.  On the low-DPI        */
  /*    screens, however, the situation is different.  The pixels are too  */
  /*    large for most of the details of a glyph and shades of gray are    */
  /*    the norm rather than the exception.                                */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    This is relevant because all our screens have a second problem:    */
  /*    they are not linear.  1~+~1 is not~2.  Twice the value does not    */
  /*    result in twice the brightness.  When a pixel is only 50% covered, */
  /*    the coverage map says 50% black, and this translates to a pixel    */
  /*    value of 128 when you use 8~bits per channel (0-255).  However,    */
  /*    this does not translate to 50% brightness for that pixel on our    */
  /*    sRGB and gamma~2.2 screens.  Due to their non-linearity, they      */
  /*    dwell longer in the darks and only a pixel value of about 186      */
  /*    results in 50% brightness – 128 ends up too dark on both bright    */
  /*    and dark backgrounds.  The net result is that dark text looks      */
  /*    burnt-out, pixely and blotchy on bright background, bright text    */
  /*    too frail on dark backgrounds, and colored text on colored         */
  /*    background (for example, red on green) seems to have dark halos or */
  /*    `dirt' around it.  The situation is especially ugly for diagonal   */
  /*    stems like in `w' glyph shapes where the quality of FreeType's     */
  /*    anti-aliasing depends on the correct display of grays.  On         */
  /*    high-DPI screens where smaller, fully black pixels reign supreme,  */
  /*    this doesn't matter, but on our low-DPI screens with all the gray  */
  /*    shades, it does.  0% and 100% brightness are the same things in    */
  /*    linear and non-linear space, just all the shades in-between        */
  /*    aren't.                                                            */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    The blending function for placing text over a background is        */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    {                                                                  */
  /*      dst = alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * dst    ,                       */
  /*    }                                                                  */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    which is known as the OVER operator.                               */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    To correctly composite an antialiased pixel of a glyph onto a      */
  /*    surface,                                                           */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    1. take the foreground and background colors (e.g., in sRGB space) */
  /*       and apply gamma to get them in a linear space,                  */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    2. use OVER to blend the two linear colors using the glyph pixel   */
  /*       as the alpha value (remember, the glyph bitmap is an alpha      */
  /*       coverage bitmap), and                                           */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    3. apply inverse gamma to the blended pixel and write it back to   */
  /*       the image.                                                      */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    Internal testing at Adobe found that a target inverse gamma of~1.8 */
  /*    for step~3 gives good results across a wide range of displays with */
  /*    an sRGB gamma curve or a similar one.                              */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    This process can cost performance.  There is an approximation that */
  /*    does not need to know about the background color; see              */
  /*    https://bel.fi/alankila/lcd/ and                                   */
  /*    https://bel.fi/alankila/lcd/alpcor.html for details.               */
  /*                                                                       */
  /*    *ATTENTION*: Linear blending is even more important when dealing   */
  /*    with subpixel-rendered glyphs to prevent color-fringing!  A        */
  /*    subpixel-rendered glyph must first be filtered with a filter that  */
  /*    gives equal weight to the three color primaries and does not       */
  /*    exceed a sum of 0x100, see section @lcd_filtering.  Then the       */
  /*    only difference to gray linear blending is that subpixel-rendered  */
  /*    linear blending is done 3~times per pixel: red foreground subpixel */
  /*    to red background subpixel and so on for green and blue.           */
  /*                                                                       */
  FT_EXPORT( FT_Error )
  FT_Render_Glyph( FT_GlyphSlot    slot,
                   FT_Render_Mode  render_mode );
```

Does anyone have an idea what I could've done wrong?